# Count Unique words in a string in C#

Tags: c#

Suppose a string like this.

String: I have a car.I had bought it two years ago.I like it very much.

i need to find out only unique words from it.like unique words in this string are 
   have,a,car,had,bought,it,two,years etc. the words are appear in the string just once. i have tried it with linq. please take look.

```
string testingtext="I have a car.I had bought it two years ago.I like it very    much.";
MatchCollection Wordcollection = Regex.Matches(testingtext, @"[\S]+");

          string[] array =     Wordcollection.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).Distinct().OrderBy(y => y).ToArray();
```

Comment: Please take look. But where !

Answer (score 2):

`Distinct` cannot be used for this task. `Distinct` will simply remove all duplicates of a word; you'll get every words anyway whether they were unique or not.

Instead, you need to use `GroupBy`. It will make a new Key-Value list, with the words and each occurrences.

Once you have that, simply take each key for which the group contains only one value (i.e. the word appears only once in the string):

```
    string testingtext = "I have a car I had bought it two years ago I like it very much.";

    IEnumerable<string> allWords = testingtext.Split(' ');
    IEnumerable<string> uniqueWords = allWords.GroupBy(w => w).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key);
```

---

You might also want to clean your input text beforehand to remove the punctuation, if you want to treat `car` and `car.` as the same word.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your issue

```
string MyStr = "I have a car.I had bought it two years ago.I like it very much";
var wrodList = MyStr.Split(null);
var output = wrodList.GroupBy(x => x).Select(y => new Word { charchter = y.Key, repeat = y.Count() }).OrderBy(z=>z.repeat);
foreach (var item in output)
{
    textBoxfile.Text += item.charchter +" : "+ item.repeat+Environment.NewLine;
}
```

You also need to create a class (word)

```
public class word
{
    public string  charchter { get; set; }
    public int repeat { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] wordsArray = testingtext.Replace("."," ").Split(' ');
int carCounter = 0;
int haveCounter = 0;
//...

foreach(String word in wordsArray )
{
if(word.Equals("car"))
  carCounter++;
if(word.Equals("have"))
  haveCounter++;
//...
}
```

after that you know how many words you have... simple

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for *Linq*, `HashSet<String>` is quite enough

```
  String source = "I have a car I had bought it two years ago I like it very much.";
  //TODO: check this    
  Char[] separators = new Char[] {' ', '\r', '\n', '\t', ',', '.', ';', '!', '?'};

  HashSet<String> uniqueWords = 
    new HashSet<String>(source.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)), 
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  // 13
  Console.Write(uniqueWords.Count);
  ...
  // I, have, a, car, had, bought, it, two, years, ago, like, very, much
  ConsoleWrite(String.Join(", ", uniqueWords));
```

Please note, that such kind of solutions work in simple cases only; *word* in natural languages is a *vague notion* so in general case of NLP (Batural Language Processing) you have to use a special designed libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int GetUniqueWordsCount(string txt)
    {
        // Use regular expressions to replace characters
        // that are not letters or numbers with spaces.
        txt = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]").Replace(txt, " ");

        // Split the text into words.
        var words = txt.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Use LINQ to get the unique words.
        var wordQuery = words.Distinct();

        return wordQuery.Count();

        //If you want words
        //return word_query.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a HashSet of string

```
    string testingtext = "I have a car.I had bought it two years ago.I like it very    much.";
    string[] words = testingtext.Split(' ');
    HashSet<string> uniqueWords = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        uniqueWords.Add(word);
    }
```